# NullPointer using GSON implementing Cryptsy API

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm in the process of writing a Java API for accessing Cryptsy's API. I am running into a problem with a NullPointerException when trying to deserialize a particular api call.

The problem line occurs in the Adapter class:

`JsonObject orderbookObj = json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("return");`

API Call: `http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=orderdata`

JSON Output:

```
{
  "success":1,
  "return":
  {
    "ASC":
    {
      "marketid":"111",
      "label":"ASC\/LTC",
      "primaryname":"AsicCoin",
      "primarycode":"ASC",
      "secondaryname":"LiteCoin",
      "secondarycode":"LTC",
      "sellorders":
      [
        {
          "price":"0.00004197",
          "quantity":"1536.00000000",
          "total":"0.06446592"
        },...
      ],
      "buyorders":
      [
        {
          "price":"0.00003957",
          "quantity":"7147.96283059",
          "total":"0.28284489"
        },...
      ]
    },
    "CENT":
    {
      ....
```

Base class for all serialized objects

```
public class Result {
private int success;
private String error;

public Result() {
    error = "";
}

// Getters and Setters
}
```

This class holds information about a buy/sell at a particular price.

```
public class GeneralOrder {

private double price;
private double quantity;
private double total;

public GeneralOrder(){}

// Getters and Setters
}
```

This is the class that would hold all the information associated with "ASC" or "CENT"

```
public class GeneralOrderbook {

private int marketid ;
private String label ;
private String primarycode ;
private String primaryname ;
private String secondarycode ;
private String secondaryname ; 

@SerializedName("sellorders")
private GeneralOrder[] sellorders;

@SerializedName("buyorders")
private GeneralOrder[] buyorders;

public GeneralOrderbook(){}

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

These next to classes are used during the deserializing

```
public class GeneralMarketData{
private GeneralMarket[] markets;

public GeneralMarketData(){}

// Getters and Setters
}

public class GeneralOrderbookReturn extends Result{

@SerializedName("return")
private GeneralOrderbookData data;

public GeneralOrderbookReturn(){}

// Getters and Setters
}
```

Class that provides the custom deserialization

```
public class GeneralOrderbookAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<GeneralOrderbookData> {

public GeneralOrderbookData deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    GeneralOrderbookData god = new GeneralOrderbookData();
    JsonObject orderbookObj = json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("return");
    List<GeneralOrderbook> orderbooks = new ArrayList<GeneralOrderbook>();
    Iterator<Entry<String, JsonElement>> itr = orderbookObj.entrySet().iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        GeneralOrderbook orderbook = context.deserialize(itr.next().getValue(), GeneralOrderbook.class);
        orderbooks.add(orderbook);
    }
    god.setOrderbook(orderbooks.toArray(new GeneralOrderbook[0]));
    return god;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` is a top-level field in the returned JSON object, which it appears you're mapping to your `Result` class. Given that, the `Result` class should look like:

```
public class Result {
    private int success;
    @SerializedName("return")
    private MyClassThatModelsReturn data;
    private String error;

    public Result() {
        error = "";
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Without knowing anything about the data you're attempting to model, are "ASC", "CENT" etc textual ticker-like symbols or something? If so, glancing over your classes it appears that could be modeled as:

```
public class Result {
    private int success;
    @SerializedName("return")
    private Map<String, GeneralOrderbook> data;
    private String error;

    // Don't initialize error in constructor, just check for null
    public boolean isError() {
        return error != null;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Comment: Yes, "ASC" and "CENT" are String ticker symbols.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get it working correctly with you help.